# How to check image against trained model while still displaying camera recording?

Tags: python, multithreading, keras, opencv

I have this python program which with the help `OpenCV (cv2)` opens a camera session. I have set an area of interest where an image is being extracted from the camera recording and is being passed at a trained `keras` model as a parameter to get a prediction. My question is how could I check against the model only every 10 seconds? I tried using `time.sleep(10)`  which freezes the whole window (as it takes place inside the while loop) for 10 seconds. That means that the whole recording stops every 10 seconds, whereas I wanna be able to record constantly and check against the model only every 10 seconds.
This is my code so far:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
import time

#import playsound

# wait for the sound to finish playing?
blocking = True

model = keras.models.load_model("model2.h5")
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

####region of interest dimensions
startX =  800
startY = 0
finishX = 1200
finishY = 400
while(1):
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if ret:
        ### displays video recording and region of interest
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
        display = cv2.rectangle(frame.copy(),(startX,startY),(finishX,finishY),(0,0,255),2) 
        cv2.imshow('Total Input',display)
        ROI = frame[startY:finishY, startX:finishX].copy()
        cv2.imshow('Region of Interest', ROI)
         
        #pauses for 10 seconds
        time.sleep(10)

        img = cv2.resize(display, (128, 128)) #R
        img = img.reshape(1, 128, 128, 3)
        predictions = model.predict(img) # Make predictions towards the test set
        predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions) # Get index of the predicted label from prediction
        print(predicted_label)
        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
          break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am thinking if I should maybe use a thread but I am not really familiar with threads in python. Does anyone have an idea how this could be done?

Answer (score 2):

I usually use frame ID for this. Basically, your model will only predict after n frames. Here's the code how to use it. You can edit how many frames you want to skip:

```
frame_id =0    
while(1):
  frame_id +=1
  ret, frame = cam.read()
  if ret:
    ### displays video recording and region of interest
    frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)
    display = cv2.rectangle(frame.copy(),(startX,startY),(finishX,finishY),(0,0,255),2) 
    cv2.imshow('Total Input',display)
    ROI = frame[startY:finishY, startX:finishX].copy()
    cv2.imshow('Region of Interest', ROI)
     
    #pauses for 10 seconds
    time.sleep(10)

    img = cv2.resize(display, (128, 128)) #R
    img = img.reshape(1, 128, 128, 3)
    if fram_id % 10 == 0:
        predictions = model.predict(img) # Make predictions towards the test set
        predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions) # Get index of the predicted label from prediction
        print(predicted_label)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run a check in your while loop to see if ten seconds have passed, and only then run your function and reset the timer. Something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

last_time = datetime.now()

while(1):
    # Other stuff

    if (datetime.now() - last_time).total_seconds() > 10:
        last_time = datetime.now()
        img = cv2.resize(display, (128, 128)) #R
        img = img.reshape(1, 128, 128, 3)
        predictions = model.predict(img) # Make predictions towards the test set
        predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions) # Get index of the predicted label from prediction
        print(predicted_label)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a variable that indicates the last time that You have made the prediction. Then, in each iteration compare time with that variable to see whether it is the right time for another prediction or not.

**Use time.time():**

I used `time.time()` method , which returns time is seconds, for tracking time:

```
last_prediction_time = time.time()
```

**Here is what I did inside the while loop:**

```
# Make predictions every 10 seconds:

if last_prediction_time - time.time() >= 10:
    img = cv2.resize(display, (128, 128))  # R
    img = img.reshape(1, 128, 128, 3)
    predictions = model.predict(img)  # Make predictions towards the test set
    predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions)  # Get index of the predicted label from prediction
    print(predicted_label)

    # update the last prediction time
    last_prediction_time = time.time()
```

**Everything together:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
import time

# import playsound

# wait for the sound to finish playing?
blocking = True

model = keras.models.load_model("model2.h5")
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

####region of interest dimensions
startX = 800
startY = 0
finishX = 1200
finishY = 400

last_prediction_time = time.time()

while (1):
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    if ret:
        ### displays video recording and region of interest
        frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)
        display = cv2.rectangle(frame.copy(), (startX, startY), (finishX, finishY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
        cv2.imshow('Total Input', display)
        ROI = frame[startY:finishY, startX:finishX].copy()
        cv2.imshow('Region of Interest', ROI)

        # Make predictions every 10 seconds:

        if last_prediction_time - time.time() >= 10:
            img = cv2.resize(display, (128, 128))  # R
            img = img.reshape(1, 128, 128, 3)
            predictions = model.predict(img)  # Make predictions towards the test set
            predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions)  # Get index of the predicted label from prediction
            print(predicted_label)

            # update the last prediction time
            last_prediction_time = time.time()

        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```